# I am getting flickering/tearing at login screen on wake up...anyway to fix this?

Tags: flicker

I am getting some flickering(or should i say tearing?)  when waking up...is there a way to fix it or is it how it is supposed to be:

https://youtu.be/T1wvXLaZh3A

sometimes it is worse than the video...sometimes the flickering/tearing happens to the desktop too when the desktop appears for the first time after login.

```
Info:
Ubuntu 20.04
Intel Core m5-6Y57 
Intel® HD Graphics 515
Xorg
Intel modesetting Driver. (checked the log at ~/.local/share/xorg/)
No .conf files for Intel at /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ or /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely hardware related, part of the power up sequence of the screen or backlight.   I see it happen often on devices regardless of operating system.

Comment: The thing is, sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't...I am using the Intel modesetting driver(20.04's default?) this looks like a tearing issue...any settings in Ubuntu to enable Vsync ? but then again, the modesetting driver doesn't have a Vsync option...